# How to put watermak on video with FFMPEG,without resizing the watermark because of video resolution?

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg

I'm looking for a way that the watermark picture does not get resized,if the video resolution is high or less. Right now I have this problem, if I upload a video like 720p the watermark is really small and when I upload a video that is 240p the watermark is really big. I would just like it to be only one size. Can it do that automatically? So no matter what the resolution is the of the video the image does not resizes and stays where I put it? Here's the code I'm using right now

```
if ($ffmpeg_ver == "old") {
                    $watermark = '-vf "movie='.$tv_logo_path.' [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=10:10 [out]" ';
            } else { 
                    $watermark = '-i '.$tv_logo_path.' -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" ';
            }
```

Comment: if there are only so many resolutions your working with care a few different watermark files, otherwise resize on the fly